# Not able to push the data into Azure event hub

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I am trying to push the data sample data into the Azure event hub but I am not able to do so.

```
import azure.functions as func
from azure.eventhub import EventData
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient
from azure.identity.aio import DefaultAzureCredential


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n" f"Name: {myblob.name}\n" f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    event_hub_connection_string = "Endpoint=sb://event-hub-namespace/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=sharedaccesskey"
    event_hub_name = "event_hub_name"
    
    
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(event_hub_connection_string, eventhub_name=event_hub_name)
    
    # event_data = "this is the first message"
    event_data = EventData(b'Hello, Event Hub!')
    with producer:
        producer.send_batch(event_data)
```

I am getting the below error and I am not sure If I am passing the correct connection string as well.

```
Result: Failure Exception: RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0'. Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 479, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 752, in _run_sync_func return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) File "/home/site/wwwroot/event-hub-test/__init__.py", line 15, in main producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(event_hub_connection_string, eventhub_name=event_hub_name) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/eventhub/aio/_producer_client_async.py", line 517, in from_connection_string return cls(**constructor_args) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/eventhub/aio/_producer_client_async.py", line 181, in __init__ ALL_PARTITIONS: self._create_producer() File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/eventhub/aio/_producer_client_async.py", line 354, in _create_producer handler = EventHubProducer( # type: ignore File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/eventhub/aio/_producer_async.py", line 110, in __init__ self._lock = asyncio.Lock(**self._internal_kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/locks.py", line 81, in __init__ self._loop = events.get_event_loop() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the imports are bringing in the async version of the clients and the azure function is running in sync.

Please make the following changes and try running the function again

```py
import azure.functions as func
from azure.eventhub import EventData
from azure.eventhub import EventHubProducerClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n" f"Name: {myblob.name}\n" f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    event_hub_connection_string = "Endpoint=sb://event-hub-namespace/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=sharedaccesskey"
    event_hub_name = "event_hub_name"
    
    
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(event_hub_connection_string, eventhub_name=event_hub_name)
    
    # event_data = "this is the first message"
    event_data = EventData(b'Hello, Event Hub!')
    with producer:
        producer.send_batch(event_data)
```

you can find more samples in our repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples)